# In a bus there are $15$ passengers and the bus makes $4$ stops. What's the probability that all $15$ get off at the same stop?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, proof-verification

In my first attempt, I said: "Well, each passenger, as a human being, chooses where to get off. So, for all to get off at stop 1, the probability would be $(1/4)^{15}$. Since there are $4$ stops, the probability required would be $(1/4)^{14}$ which is approx. $0.0000003  \%$"

Then I saw the correct solution which uses stars and bars: There are $\binom{15+4-1}{4-1}$ possible distributions for the passengers. Of all of them, only four correspond to the passengers getting off at a single stop(All at $1$, All at $2$...). Then the probability required would be $4/\binom{18}{3}= 0.5 \%$ approx.

Is that really the correct answer?

Comment: Your first calculation is correct.

Comment: Stars and bars makes little sense here.  Your answer of $\frac{1}{4^{14}}$ is correct proved (a) each stop is equally likely for each passenger and (b) each passenger's decision is independent of the other passengers.  But in reality, some stops are more popular than others and people often travel in groups, so neither assumption is reasonable and the real-life probability is likely to be much larger

Comment: The second method is misconceived because the possible configurations are not equi-probable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each of the $15$ passengers makes his own decision (assumed independently of the other passengers) there  are $4^{15}$ ways the passengers can get off. Exactly $4$ of these have all passengers getting off at the same stop. It follows that the probability in question is
$${4\over 4^{15}}=3.7253\cdot10^{-9}\ .$$